# Language Bar Turn Off Advanced Text services Global Policy

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, active-directory, windows

Is there a way I can set a global policy to turn off advanced text services so I can stop having to click this checkbox 8 million times?

Client base is all Windows XP and the domain controller is Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Furthermore, once you know the registry setting, you can create a custom [Administrative Template](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323639) and deploy this via group policies.

Answer (score 2):

The Language Bar is annoying and, as far as I can tell, useless to the majority of users.  I use a registry edit to remove it...

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{540D8A8B-1C3F-4E32-8132-530F6A502090}]
@="Language bar"
"MenuTextPUI"="@%SystemRoot%\System32\msutb.dll,-325"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoSaveSettings"=dword:00000000

Comment: Can you explain what that 2nd key does?

Comment: If i remember correctly....running only the first key leaves the help icon in the taskbar.  It didnt make sense, but when I Googled it (months ago) thats what I came up with.  I could be wrong about that.  I tried 3-4 different methods, including a batch file, but this is what ended up working for me.

Comment: If for you "the majority of users" means single-language speaking users then you are right.

Comment: @Petr which for the USA that means the language bar is useless ;)

Answer (score 1):

Also related: ["How to turn off the speech recognition and handwriting recognition features"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326526)